# Connecting SQL Server 2008 R2 with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to connect SQL Server 2008 R2 to Visual Studio 2010. It seems that the versions are not consistent, it's a little strange for me since SQL Server is 2008 and VS is 2010!!! Since I'm a new user and cant upload image here you may find a screen shot of the error here:

http://img4up.com/up2/51497019025204797538.jpg

Would appreciate if anyone can help me.

Best Regards

Comment: Your image link is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using "Microsoft SQL Server Database File" use "Microsoft SQL Server"[image: Selection WIndow]

Then connect using the server address and user information.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010 installs SQL Server Express 2008 and your database was created with SQL Server 2008 R2. You'll need to upgrade to SQL Server Express 2008 R2 to open this database.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the file option if the instance of SQL Server already exists and you plan to create a persistent database there (or use an existing one). You should be selecting a proper instance of SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the same steps as *iamkrillin/Stecenko Ruslan* suggested., If you had provided a username and password during the installation of SQL Server R2 , then choose the radio button "Use SQL Authentication" instead of "Use Windows Authentication"., in the "Add Connection" dialog of Visual Studio 2010.